# PHP search different fields in a table and show respective results

Tags: php, mysql, search, select, distinct

Maybe I'm not thinking this through correctly but I have a company table with:

```
name
address
city
state
zip
```

I want to search two fields, name and city.

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT    city, name 
FROM               companies 
WHERE              city 
LIKE               '%$search%' 
OR                 name 
LIKE               '%$search%'
```

and the results code is:

```
echo '<a href="city.php?city=' . $results['city'] . '">' 
    . $results['city'] . '</a>';
```

Now this only takes into account if the person searches for a city.  How do I get it to show the page if someone searches for a company name?  Something like:

```
echo '<a href="company.php?co=' . $results['name'] . '">' 
    . $results['name'] . '</a>';
```

Is there any way to show the proper result depending on what they searched for?

Comment: Mind reading, but it will only happen in PHP 7.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this?
How can I make the results show? Possible to put an if statement in there before the results?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one search box, how can you know what the user is looking for?

You could add checkboxes/radio buttons to offer the choice between `city` or `name`.

If you don't want to do that then you **do not** know what the user is searching for. You can however run two queries, one for `city` then another one for `name`. If you get results you will at least know where they are coming from.

Comment: I can't recall where but I know I have seen search boxes that allow for searching completely different things. I will try to find it and post it here but in the meantime I do like your suggestion of a radio button.

Comment: Yes, and as I said you can **search** for different things, but you cannot necessarily know in advance **what** the user is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare the two fields of the results to the search text, to know what matched it: city or name.
Something like:

`if($search === $results['city']) echo '<a href="city.php?city=' . $results['city'] . '">'. $results['city'] . '</a>'; elseif($search === $results['name'])

        echo '<a href="company.php?co=' . $results['name'] . '">'. $results['name'] . '</a>';`

Not sure if I understood right...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that is exactly what I wanted to do but the only thing is that I have the results being filtered by each key press (by javascript) so the $search may not actually match the $results['city'] or $results['name']. Any other way I could check for the match?